# For Loop to determine lowest value of a list in python

Tags: python

In the below, I have several questions. Firstly, why do we not define the starting value of `i`? In WHILE loops I came across this was the case. Secondly, I am finding it difficult to understand the "sequence" of what is happening. I understand that `m = L[0] = 1` but the subsequent steps are not clear to me.

```
L=[1,2,4,-5,7,9,3,2]

m = L[0]
for i in L:
    if i<m:
       m = i
print(m)
```

Comment: The for loop yo have defined starts at the beginning of the list and assigns each value to ```i``` in turn. Try printing ```i``` to see what is happening

Comment: There is no "starting" value of `i`; `i` is assigned a new value at the start of each iteration.

Comment: you can also use ```min()``` to determine the lowest number

Answer (score 0):

For loops in python are really "for each" loops. Read it as "for each value 'i' in list 'L', do...".

`i` is not an index, it is the actual element in the list `L`.

So we set the initial minimum to just the first element of the list, and we say, for each element in our list, if there is a value smaller than our current minimum, we'll set our minimum to that element.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to define the starting value of i to make the program more variable to other cases. M is going to be the lowest value because that is what we are printing out. So if i is lower than m we want i to be m. The for loop goes through every number in the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
L=[1,2,4,-5,7,9,3,2]

m = L[0] # start with m as the first value of your list which is 1.
for i in L: # for i in L means for i being consecutively 1 then 2 then 4 then -5 etc...
    if i<m: # if i is less than m the starting point, give the value of i to m
            # example if m = 1 and i =-3 after this condition m will take the value -3
       m = i
print(m) # when you finish looping over all the examples print my m value
```

I would suggest writing the algorithm on a paper and you will see how easy it is.

```
m=1
loop
i=1
i<1? No.
go back to loop
i=2 
i<1? No.
go back to loop
i=4 
i<1? No.
go back to loop
i=-5 
i<1? YES.
m = -5
go back to loop 
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

The `for` loop proceeds via a form of hypothesis testing. First, we establish a *loop invariant*: something that remains true before and after each iteration. In this case, it is that `m` is the smallest value in the list that we have seen *so far*.

When we initialize `m = L[0]`, it is true: having looked only at `L[0]`, `m` is the smallest value we've seen so far.

Inside the loop, `i` takes on each value in the list exactly once. We compare it to `m`, and if `i` is indeed smaller, we use *it* as the new value of `m`. So after each iteration, `m` remains the smallest value seen so far.

Once the loop completes, having set `i` to each element in turn, we can conclude that `m` is not only the smallest value in `L` that we've seen so far, but it is the smallest value in `L`, *period*, because we have looked at every value in `L`.

---

The `for` loop is equivalent to the following `while` loop:

```
_index = 0
while True:
    try:
        i = L[_index]
    except IndexError:
        break

    if i < m:
        m = i

    _index += 1
```

As you can see, we initialize `_index` to 0, and increment it explicitly at the end of each iteration. The `for` loop essentially keeps track of `_index` for us. `i`, on the other hand, is not initialized so much as it is *derived* from the current values of `L` and `_index`.

---

More generally, `for` loops don't manage repeated indexing operations, but are based on the iterator protocol. A `for` loop like

```
for i in L:
    ...
```

is roughly equivalent to

```
_itr = iter(L)
while True:
    try:
        i = next(_itr)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way to do it without using a for loop so you can run your whatever code you want to run using the `min()` function for example in here:

```
L=[1,2,4,-5,7,9,3,2]

print(min(L)
```

I would recommend using something like this because its easier faster and runs smoother than the code in your question. The code in your question first runs a for loop that gets all the values out of the list and store them as i and runs threw them then it goes to the if statement which checks if the value which is `i` in this example is smaller than `m` which has the value of `1` then rewrites the variable `m` which was the value `1` to the value that is smaller than `i` which is `-5` and as you see there this is a lot of function to run throw and that makes your code slower if the code consist of many lines.(Tip: always try using as minimum `for` loops or `if` statements as you can.)

your example:

```
L=[1,2,4,-5,7,9,3,2]

m = L[0]
for i in L:
    if i<m:
       m = i
print(m)
```